# django logging set context globally per request?

Tags: python, django, logging

Lets say I want to log like this formatting string :

```
%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(funcName)s %(message)s %(user_id)
```

It can be done using this type of logging command :

`logging.error('Error fetching information', extra = { 'user_id': 22 } )`

This will add the current userid to logging messages for current request.

But the extra dict needs to be added to every logging call.

Is there a good way to add this context in a common function in django (eg Middleware, or index function of a view ), so that the extra dictionary with user id is set, and all further logging calls in the current request also log the current user.

Comment: Why is `mawimawi`'s answer not acceptable? Is it because of thread-local usage, or something else?

Comment: Vinay Sajip, some rep points will die alone. That's how it works here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @VinaySajip , yes, trying to avoid the usage of thread-local and an extra middleware. If there is a way possible by extending the logging class, that would be great.

Comment: I updated my answer to suggest an approach which avoids thread locals or middleware.

Comment: unchain it. :p on a more serious note this:
https://github.com/jedie/django-tools/blob/master/django_tools/middlewares/ThreadLocal.py

Comment: DhruvPathak : Why do you want to avoid a middleware? I don't get the reason.

Comment: @mawimawi Not middleware, I want to avoid thread locals to be specific

Comment: @DhruvPathak: Since you want the current user id (which is only in the request object) globally available without a middleware which knows about the request and can make it available to you, there is no other way than to put either the request object or the user id as a parameter to your logging call.  I still can not understand why you don't want to use threadlocals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There exists a ThreadLocal middleware on https://github.com/jedie/django-tools/blob/master/django_tools/middlewares/ThreadLocal.py which helps you with your issue in making the current request available everywhere.

So what you need to do is add the middleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting, and create a function somewhere like this:

```
 from django_tools.middlewares import ThreadLocal
 def log_something(levelname, module, funcname, message):
     user = ThreadLocal.get_current_user()
     # do your logging here. "user" is the user object and the user id is in user.pk
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible approach without thread locals or middleware: in your `views.py`, say, have a dict mapping threads to requests, and a lock to serialise access to it:

```
from threading import RLock
shared_data_lock = RLock()
request_map = {}

def set_request(request):
    with shared_data_lock:
        request_map[threading.current_thread()] = request
```

Create the following filter and attach to the handlers which need to output request-specific info:

```
import logging
class RequestFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        with shared_data_lock:
            request = request_map.get(threading.current_thread())
        if request:
            # Set data from the request into the record, e.g.
            record.user_id = request.user.id
        return True
```

Then, as the first statement of each view, set the request in the map:

```
def my_view(request, ...):
    set_request(request)
    # do your other view stuff here
```

With this setup, you should find that your log output contains the relevant request-specific info.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a [custom log formatter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#formatter-objects). Taken in conjunction with mawimawi's answer to include the threadlocal information, your format method could automatically take the information and add it to each logged message.

There are a couple of things to think about: First, threadlocal variables can be dangerous and, worse, leak information, if you deploy in a way that uses a threadpool.  Second, you need to be cautious how you write your formatter in case it gets called in a context that doesn't have the threadlocal information.